# Actionscript 3: How to make movieclip variables work with variables on stage (Healthbar Help)

Tags: variables, actionscript, layer, movieclip

I am totally new at this whole programming thing, and I really need help. So basically, I'm trying to make a healthbar that will increase or decrease depending on what button is clicked. I made a healthbar movieclip with 101 frames (I included zero) and put this in the actionscript layer of the movieclip:

```
var health:Number = 0;

if(health == 0)
{
        gotoAndStop("1")
}

if(health == 1)
{
        gotoAndStop("2")
}

if(health == 2)
{
        gotoAndStop("3")
}
```

and on and on like so. Basically, on the stage itself, I have a button called fortyfiveup_btn that is commanded to do this:

```
var health:Number = 0;

fortyfiveup_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fortyfiveupClick);
function fortyfiveupClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    health = health+45
}
```

I quickly realized that both health variables, the one for the button and the one for the healthbar will not interact. How can I make it so if the button is clicked, the health goes to the relevant frame or percentage?

Thanks for any answers, and I appreciate all the help I can get :)

Comment: For understanding: inside the movieclip you do the `if(health == x) gotoAndStop(x); ` And on the stage you do the `health = health + 45;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `answer == yes` to my comment you should do this:

You need to give the movieclip an instancename (perhaps lifebar) and from stage you can access the health inside the "lifebar" with `lifebar.health`.

So you need this inside your stage:

```
//You can delete the var health:Number = 0;
fortyfiveup_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fortyfiveupClick);
function fortyfiveupClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    //You can write this, too: lifebar.health += 45;
    lifebar.health = lifebar.health+45;
}
```

You can even optimize your lifebar script, don't use 101 times the `if(health == x)` you can use this, too:

```
gotoAndStop(health + 1);
```

(I think this is inside an `ENTER_FRAME` event?)

**EDIT:**

Some error countermeasures:

```
//Don't let health decrease below 0
if(health < 0) health = 0;
//And don't above 100
else if(health > 100) health = 100;
gotoAndStop(health + 1);
```

Use `int` instead of `Number` when you don't use decimal numbers and `uint` when you don't use negative integers (this bugs when the number can drop under 0, so for your health we take `int`):

```
health:int = 0;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help! You made it alot simpler, but I still have one more question. I did the coding like you told me and got the compiler error of (1120: Access of undefined property health. Source: lifebar.health = health=45;) and the health movie clip does not stop. Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Hmm, this means it can't access to the lifebar.health. Is lifebar the correct instancename? Is the lifebar inside another movieclip?

Comment: Yes, it is labeled lifebar, but perhaps its because it is in the instance of: Healthbar?

Comment: Than you need to use Healthbar.lifebar.health and the movieclip is not the instancename, you need declare the instancename of each movieclip by yourself. So when the movieclip is name lifebar but the instance is Healthbar you need to use Healthbar.health

Comment: I tried that, and now I have two errors - 1119: Access of possibly undefined property lifebar through a reference with static type Class. and 1120: Access of undefined property health.

Comment: What's your current displaylist? (what movieclips are on stage and what's there instancename and what movieclips are inside this movieclip and what instancename do they have)

Comment: I'm a little confused, this is the code I have in the stage actionscript layer:
fortyfiveup_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fortyfiveupClick);
function fortyfiveupClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    Healthbar.lifebar.health = health+45;
}
and the movieclip (the healthbar movieclip) is in the instance of: Healthbar, and the instance name is lifebar.

Comment: Now I'm confused, too :) So you have a movieclip inside another movieclip? And this movieclip is on stage?

Comment: On my stage, I have one movie clip. When you double click on it, and/or edit it there are two layers. One for actions, and one for the 101 frames. This is the healthbar. On the stage itself, I have an actions layer. On that layer are the actions for my button. The button on the stage is what I want to use control the healthbar movieclip and what frame it goes to. So, just one movieclip, and just one button so far.

Comment: So you just need to reference downwards one instance, this means lifebar.health (but only if the movieclip has the instancename lifebar). Try this and change the line inside the lifebar movieclip to this: `public var health:int = 0;`

Comment: I tried that, and I got the compiler error of 1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package. source: public var health:int = 100

Comment: okay, delete the public again  but not the `var health:int = 100;`

Comment: Alright, done. Let me just post the codes I have, maybe I'm putting them all in wrong? For the button, I have: fortyfiveup_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fortyfiveupClick);
function fortyfiveupClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    lifebar.health = health+45;
}
    and for the healthbar, I have    var health:int = 100;
gotoAndStop(health + 1);

if(health < 0) health = 0;

else if(health > 100) health = 100;
gotoAndStop(health + 1);

Comment: AHHH now it made click, inside the fortyfiveupClick function: `lifebar.health = lifebar.health + 45;` We forgot to use the "lifebar" there, too.

Comment: This weren't happend with `lifebar.health += 45;` :D

Comment: Hey, it's working! Aah, thank you so much. If I manage to finish my game, I'm going to put you in the credits or something. Thanks :)